# How do I start and stop Confetti View on a single UIbutton?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode10

I am a beginner in Xcode. I am trying to make an app which displays confetti on a button click. However, when I press the button, the confetti is displayed but it never stops. It blocks the buttons and the view. I am using a Cocoapod - SAConfettiView.

This code in on Xcode 10. I believe that the Confetti blocks the main view. I use playConfetti as IBaction function.

```
@IBAction func playConfetti(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: SAConfettiView) {
    let confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    confettiView.intensity = 1
    confettiView.type = .Star
    confettiView.startConfetti()
    view.addSubview(confettiView)
}
```

Do I have to use the If-Else statement?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

To stop the `SAConfettiView` call the function,

```
confettiView.stopConfetti()
```

Change your Button Action code to the following:

```
let confettiView = SAConfettiView()

@IBAction func startClicked(_ sender: Any)
    if confettiView.isActive() {
        confettiView.stopConfetti() 
        confettiView.removeFromSuperview() 
    }
    else{
        confettiView = SAConfettiView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        confettiView.intensity = 1
        confettiView.type = .Star
        confettiView.startConfetti()
        view.addSubview(confettiView)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(sender as! UIButton)
    }
}
```

Comment: Three more things: 1) no need to cast `sender`, it is already a `UIButton` which is a subclass of `UIView`. 2) you can't access `self` in your `let` statement because `self` isn't available until after the class has been initialized.  Instead, set the frame of confettiView inside the function. 3) Add `confettiView.removeFromSuperview()` after you stop.

Comment: I tried updating my code as per your suggestion, but there is no difference in the execution :(

Comment: I added "self.view.sendSubviewToBack(confettiView)" in the if-statement, but there is no change. Is there any way I can add duration to the confetti??

Comment: In your code, is your button is visible after the button click?

Comment: @VinuJacob it is visible, but it gets blocked.

Comment: Means, can you perform the button action or not?

Comment: @VinuJacob when the app launches and I click the button, it works. But then the confetti doesn't stop and both the buttons get blocked. Though they are still visible, they do not work on the click.

Comment: @VinuJacob I updated my code but the issue hasn't resolved. Can we make a class for the UI Button Extension?

Comment: @PrachiModi don't try to update your code, try my code. I don't know why you are using `@IBAction func playConfetti(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: SAConfettiView)` declaration. Put a `UIButton` and add the ***Button Action*** `@IBAction func startClicked(_ sender: Any)`, inside that add my code. Don't forget to declare your  `SAConfettiView` variable globally. Like `let confettiView = SAConfettiView()`. I tried this in my code. It is working fine.

Comment: If you want to stop the `confettiView` like an animation, comment the code `confettiView.removeFromSuperview()`